# Trusted Identity Token Issuer - remove claim provider name

Tags: claims-based-auth, people-picker, adfs, claim-provider

I have sharepoint 2010 with ADFS. I also created custom claims provider and set it's name as `ClaimProviderName` property of SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer for ADFS. But now I'd like the default ADFS people picker back again. But when I try to set `ClaimProviderName` to empty string, I'm getting error that claim provider does not exist. I tried empty string, $null, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change the claimprovider back to the original one. You'll have to remove the SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and create it again with the right settings. Be sure to use the same name if you want your existing users to be able to login again.

1. Remove your SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer from all web applications
2. Delete your SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer
3. Create a new SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer with the same settings as before (but without the settings you're trying to remove)
4. Configure your web applications to use the SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer again

Comment: I'd just like to add that if for any reason your claims provider stops searching you may have to do this.

Comment: If you were forced to use a different name for whatever reason, you can change the LoginName with Move-SPUser.  (M$ told me it wasn't supported, but it worked perfectly for me for 4200 users)  Then the users permissions are restored with the LoginName change.